# Fix for PHP parsing script output?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, csv

I have a PHP Script that parses plain text and then outputs that text in a CSV format, but I'm not getting the output exactly the way I need. I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
<?php
$text = "1. Bonus: Name some things about US history. For 10 points each:
[10] Name the first president of the United States of America.
ANSWER: George Washington
[10] How many original colonies were there?
ANSWER: 13
[10] How many states exist today?
ANSWER: 50

2. Bonus: Name some stuff. For 10 points each:
[10] What does lol mean?
ANSWER: Laugh Out Loud
[10] What is the capital of Virginia?
ANSWER: Richmond
[10] What language am I writing in?
ANSWER: PHP";


function text_to_csv( $text = null ) {
    $lines  = explode( "\n", $text );
    $data   = null;
    foreach( $lines as $line ) {
        $line = trim( $line );
        if ( empty( $line ) ) {
            continue;
        }
        if ( preg_match( '/^\[10\](.+?)$/', $line, $quest ) ) {
            $data .=  "|".trim( $quest[0] )."|,";
        }

        if ( preg_match( '/^([0-9]+)\.(.+?)$/', $line, $quest ) ) {
            $data .= "|".trim( $quest[1] )."|,";
            $data .= "|".trim( $quest[2] )."|,";
        }
        if ( preg_match( '/^ANSWER\:(.+?)$/', $line, $quest ) ) {
            $data .= "|".trim( $quest[1] )."|,";
        }
    }
    return rtrim($data,",");
}

echo text_to_csv( $text );

?>
```

This outputs the following:

```
|1|,|Bonus: Name some things about US history. For 10 points each:|,|[10] Name the first president of the United States of America.|,|George Washington|,|[10] How many original colonies were there?|,|13|,|[10] How many states exist today?|,|50|,|2|,|Bonus: Name some stuff. For 10 points each:|,|[10] What does lol mean?|,|Laugh Out Loud|,|[10] What is the capital of Virginia?|,|Richmond|,|[10] What language am I writing in?|,|PHP|
```

The whole string is on one line. I would like for it to break after each 'bonus' set (like so):

```
|1|,|Bonus: Name some things about US history. For 10 points each:|,|[10] Name the first president of the United States of America.|,|George Washington|,|[10] How many original colonies were there?|,|13|,|[10] How many states exist today?|,|50|
|2|,|Bonus: Name some stuff. For 10 points each:|,|[10] What does lol mean?|,|Laugh Out Loud|,|[10] What is the capital of Virginia?|,|Richmond|,|[10] What language am I writing in?|,|PHP|
```

In this way, each 'bonus' set is on a separate line and within each line, the segments are separated by a comma (CSV format). Could anybody help me accomplish this. I'd really appreciate it. I'm fairly new to parsing and regexs.

Comment: P.S. I choose to enclose fields with a "|" rather than a quotation because some of the fields that I will be using actually contain quotations and it is easier to upload to a MySQL database this way.

Comment: Depending on your input structure you may want to split on encountering an empty line or a `x. Bonus` token. This shouldn't be hard - just add a new line in such a case.

Comment: @KarolPiczak Between each bonus is an empty line, so how would I code to split on an empty line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for a comment, though not really long enough for an answer.

If you want to split at empty lines:

```
if ( empty( $line ) ) {
    continue;
}
```

should change into:

```
if ( empty( $line ) ) {
   $data .= "\n";
   continue;
}
```